# Is compliance testing necessary for PCIE3.0 if the SOC and Wi-Fi chipset is on the same board?

Tags: layout, signal-integrity, high-speed, pcie

In my product, PCIe is just used for data transmission between SOC and Wi-Fi chipset. It's not used for any other purpose. Is compliance testing necessary for this scenario?

What type of SI characterization should I do for RX and TX?

Comment: I believe PCI-SIG Compliance is only _required_ if you want to use the PCI Express name and/or logo on your product, or if you want to advertise compatibility with PCI Express products (which is covered by PCI-SIG Interoperability Tests). I haven't gone through this process myself, though, so don't take that as an authoritative answer.

Comment: My understanding is that compliance is only necessary if you only implement one end of the link (e.g. motherboard with PCIe slot, or PCIe add-in board).  If you have a link between two chips on the same board with no connectors or anything else, then there really isn't anything to test in terms of compliance as you can't plug in an arbitrary add-in board or whatever.